# Classes of TMs for which we can solve the halting problem

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

I am trying to solve a problem concerned with a certain class of Turing machines. Namely, ones that have at most $k$ states for some fixed $k$ on binary tape alphabet, and that are deciders.

Given such a bounded machine, can we determine if it is indeed a decider? I know that for e.g. machines with bound tape we can.

Comment: except if $k$ is very small, we don't even know if the machine will stop. For exemple, with binary alphabet on empty input with unbounded tape, we only know for $k<5$ if a machine halts or not, but for $k=5$, this is a mystery (otherwise we could know the exact value of the Busy Beaver function for (5,2), but we don't). Some machines with unpredictable behaviour, possibly linked to difficult conjecture can be made with very few states.